# Inheritance, child has no attribute of parent

Tags: python, inheritance

```
from abc import ABC 


class Person(ABC):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.__name = name

class Worker(Person):
    def __init__(self,name):
        super().__init__(name)
        print(self.__name)

Worker("Ania")
```

I want output "Ania", but I have this error instead:

> 'Worker' object has no attribute '_Worker__name'

Comment: why aren't you using `self.name` ?

Comment: Double underscore results into Name Mangling. Refer [What is the meaning of single and double underscore before an object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1301369/2063361) for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `__name` to `_name` or `name`, it'll work.
In Python preceding dunders (double underscores) means Mangling. You can read more [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/5-different-meanings-of-underscore-in-python-3fafa6cd0379).

Comment: ... because of [mangling](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/name-mangling-in-python/).